# How to add html attribute to tag in a vsc snippet

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I'm wondering how to add a html attribute like `content` inside of a html tag (e. g. `meta`) to a VSC code snippet. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I think I've solved the problem by myselfe:

```
meta[name='keywords'][content='test, a test, testing']
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).